# How can I try Pull request on VSC, with dependencies on them?

Tags: github, pull-request

Soo I'm working in a team with some people and I told them to do Pull request instead of just putting everyting in the branch, but now I want to try there code, but idunno how to do it (cause' the pull request just recieves the file change, not the whole dir).

I try just running it, didn't worked out or just put create that file on mi workspace, but that is just a dumb idea.

Comment: A PR is a branch. You check out the branch locally and follow the README for how to install and run it locally. More likely you need to set up deploy previews in your PR process, as it sounds like running the project locally will be difficult for you.

Comment: @JBallin lmao, I forgot to say thx, thx :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test a pull request locally:

1. **Checkout the PR's Branch:**

   ```bash
   git fetch origin
   git checkout [branch-name]
   ```
2. **Run the Project:**
   Follow the project's README for setup instructions, including installing dependencies and running the project.